# XCTest how to perform segue that present a modal view and test presentedViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I was trying to test a segue that would present a view controller. But, it always fail. How to wait for the segue to complete? Please assist.

```
[self.viewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegueName" sender:self.viewController];
XCTAssertNotNil(self.viewController.presentedViewController, @"Failed to show modal view");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to present on a `UIViewController` whose view is not in the `UIWindow` hierarchy. Here's my solution:

```
- (void)testExample {

    //
    // Arrange
    // Storyboard
    //
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    //
    // Arrange
    // View Controller
    //
    UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController = viewController;

    //
    // Act
    //
    [viewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ModalSegue" sender:nil];

    //
    // Assert
    //
    XCTAssertNotNil(viewController.presentedViewController);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Providing a Swift 3.0 answer that also uses the Quick/Nimble framework and performs the Segue by "tapping" the button that performs the Segue in the view space.

```
        // Note: there's also a beforeEach {} that sets up the mainViewController
        describe("navigation") { 
        beforeEach {
            // Access the view to trigger MainViewController.viewDidLoad().
            let _ = mainViewController.view
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            let window = appDelegate.window
            window?.rootViewController = mainViewController
        }

        describe("the views navigationBar", closure: {
            describe("left bar button item", closure: { 
                context("when pressed", closure: { 
                    it("displays SomeViewController", closure: {
                        let item = mainViewController.navigationBar.topItem
                        let addItem = item?.leftBarButtonItem
                        tap(addItem!)
                        expect(mainViewController?.presentedViewController).toEventually(beAnInstanceOf(SomeViewController.self))
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    }
```

For Reference the tap() method:

```
    func tap(_ barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let _ = barButtonItem.target?.perform(barButtonItem.action, with: barButtonItem)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using KIF? It's an Objective-C based UI Testing framework that integrates with the Accessibility framework built in to the app (as UI Automation does). This makes it perfect for UI testing through the regular testing frameworks.

https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF

Or follow this tutorial to ensure it is what you want:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/61419/ios-ui-testing-with-kif

Hope you find your solution!